# Is it possible to set page title with ViewBag in ASPX mode?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a master page called `Default.master`. I want to set the title using `ViewBag.Title`. On my controller I have:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home";
    return View();
}
```

My `Home` view uses `Default.master` as the master view page. On the master view page I am using:

```
<title><%= ViewBag.Title %></title>
```

But I get this error:

```
The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 'System.IO.TextWriter.Write(string, params object[])' and 'System.IO.TextWriter.Write(char[])'
```

How can I use it properly?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From [this blog post](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/01/06/razor-syntax-quick-reference.aspx) I saw a syntax that I've never seen before:

```
<%: %>
```

This prints an expression, so using:

```
<%: ViewBag.Title %>
```

I got the correct value.

Comment: While this is a correct syntax, it doesn't have anything to do with the problem as stated...

Comment: @Oskar the question was a way to use ViewBag in aspx mode. This is the way, so how come it doesn't solve the question?

Answer (score 7):

Try:

```
<title><%= (string) ViewBag.Title %></title>
```

Comment: Doesn't crash but return empty.

Comment: Hmm, please paste the entire contents of your aspx file.
I just tested with a sample aspx View in an MVC3 project and the code works fine.

Comment: Sounds like your Title property is null, as Qun Wang also points out.  When you're passing a null value to the dynamic object it doesn't know how to represent it.  Casting it to String removes the ambiguity.

Comment: @Oskar if it was null would probably throw an exception because of the cast.

Answer (score 1):

your ViewBag.Title's value is null.
maybe there are some exceptions happened.
only in this case the ambiguous exception will thrown